# Amazon Transcribe with audio input streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio-streaming

Some providers such as Google, allow to send an audio stream to their server and get results as soon as the audio is processed.
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

The standard Amazon Transcribe needs the URL of an audio to get later the transcription once it has been completed. Not ideal for an `online` processing server.

Amazon Lex/Transcribe seems that have a similar feature if you use the two systems together, but I cannot find the API to use the transcription/Lex with a custom audio streaming of my choice.

Do you know if it is possible achieving it?

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Transcribe now supports streaming.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-transcribe-now-supports-real-time-transcriptions/)